# How to go from spring mvc multipartfile into zipinputstream

Tags: spring-mvc, multipartform-data, zip

I have a Spring MVC controller that accepts a MultipartFile, which will be a zip file. The problem is I can't seem to go from that to a ZipInputStream or ZipFile, so that I can go through the entries. It either closes the stream prematurely, produces an empty file, or as in the case below, zipInputStream.getNextEntry() returning null.

This is my MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/content/general-import", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleGeneralUpload(
                                  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    // hard code the signature for the moment
    String signature = "RETAILER_GROUP:*|CHANNEL:*|LOCALE:de-AT|INDUSTRY:5499";

    LOG.info("Processing file archive: {} with signature: {}.", file.getName(), signature);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("contentUpload");

    LOG.debug("File={} is empty={}.", file.getName(), file.isEmpty());
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {

        processFileZipEntry(file, signature);


        mav.addObject("form", UploadViewModel.make("/content/general-import", "Updated content with file"));

        return mav;
    } else {

        mav.addObject("form", UploadViewModel.make("/content/general-import", "Could not update content with file"));

        return mav;
    }
}
```

It delegates to the following method for processing:

```
protected void processFileZipEntry(MultipartFile file, String signature) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    LOG.debug("Processing archive with bytes={}.", file.getBytes().length);

    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

    LOG.debug("Processing archive with size={}.", file.getSize());
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        LOG.debug("Processing file={} is directory?={}.", entry.getName(), entry.isDirectory());
        // process each file, based on what it is and whether its a directory etc.
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            // if the entry is a file, extract it
            LOG.debug("Processing entry: {}",entry.getName());

            int length = (int) entry.getSize();

            Content contentToSave = null;
            if(entry.getName().contains("gif")) {
                contentToSave = Content.makeImage(entry.getName(), Content.GIF, signature, getBytesFrom(zis, "gif"));
            } else if (entry.getName().contains("png")) {
                contentToSave = Content.makeImage(entry.getName(), Content.PNG, signature, getBytesFrom(zis, "png"));
            } else if (entry.getName().contains("jpeg")) {
                contentToSave = Content.makeImage(entry.getName(), Content.JPEG, signature, getBytesFrom(zis, "jpeg"));
            } else if (entry.getName().contains("json")) {
                contentToSave = Content.makeFile(entry.getName(), Content.JSON, signature, getStringFrom(zis, length));
            } else if (entry.getName().contains("js")) {
                contentToSave = Content.makeFile(entry.getName(), Content.JS, signature, getStringFrom(zis, length));
            } else if (entry.getName().contains("css")) {
                contentToSave = Content.makeFile(entry.getName(), Content.CSS, signature, getStringFrom(zis, length));
            }

            Content contentAleadyThere = contentService.fetch(entry.getName());
            if(contentAleadyThere != null) {
                LOG.warn("Replacing file: {} with uploaded version.", contentToSave.getName());
            }

            contentService.put(contentToSave);
            LOG.info("Persisted file: {} from uploaded version.", contentToSave.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Basically, in this permutation, the file bytes are there, but there are no entries (zis.getNextEntry() does not exist. I can see that the zip file contains files, and the byte[] has about 3MB worth of stuff, so something must be going wrong with the streaming. Does anyone have a recipe for going from MultipartFile to ZipFile or ZipInputStream?

EDIT

To give you more information, I have a test harnass around this code, by using a MockMvc

```
@Test
public void testProcessingGeneralUpload() throws Exception {

    Resource template = wac.getResource("classpath:lc_content/content.zip");

    System.out.println("template content length: " + template.contentLength());
    System.out.println("template path: " + template.getFile().getPath());
    System.out.println("template filename: " + template.getFilename());



    MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile(
            "file", "content.zip", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, extractFile(template.getFile()));

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/content/general-import")
            .file(firstFile))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("contentUpload"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("form")).andReturn();

    // processing assertions
    ModelMap modelMap = mvcResult.getModelAndView().getModelMap();
    Object object = modelMap.get("form");
        assertThat(object, is(not(nullValue())));
        assertThat(object, is(instanceOf(UploadViewModel.class)));
    UploadViewModel addModel = (UploadViewModel) object;
        assertThat(addModel.getMessage(), is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(addModel.getPostUrl(), is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(addModel.getPostUrl(), is("/content/general-import"));
    assertThat(addModel.getMessage(), is("Updated content with file"));

    // persistence assertions

    assertThat(contentDao.findByName("/content/control/basket-manager.js"), is(notNullValue()) );

}
```

The extractFile method is as follows:

```
private byte[] extractFile(File zipFile) throws IOException {

    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    System.out.println("length of file: " + zipFile.length());

    byte[] output = null;

    try {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int)zipFile.length()];
        zipIn.read(data);
        zipIn.close();

        output = data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;

}
```

The length of bytes it produces is 3617817, which is the size I expect, and this is fed into the controller method at the top of this question.

I have continued working the problem. The size of the file is correct, it is a zipped file (it unpacks via the OS perfectly), and yet no ZipEntry enumeration.

Comment: Don't use `getBytes()` use `getInputStream()` instead.

Comment: Also why are you using a `ZipInputStream` to extract the file? Why aren't you just using the `FileInputStream` to construct a `MockMultipartFile`? Looks to me as if you are making things more complicated then needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would for starters rewrite some of the code instead of doing things in memory with additional byte[].

You are using Spring's `Resource` class so why not simply use the `getInputStream()` method to construct the `MockMultipartFile` as you want to upload that file.

```
Resource template = wac.getResource("classpath:lc_content/content.zip");
MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile(
        "file", "content.zip", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, template.getInputStream());
```

The same for your upload processing code the `ZipInputStream` can also be constructed on another `InputStream` which is also provided by the `MultipartFile` interface.

```
protected void processFileZipEntry(MultipartFile file, String signature) throws IOException {

    LOG.debug("Processing archive with size={}.", file.getSize());
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());
```

Wouldn't be the first time that jugling around with `byte[]` gives a problem. I also vaguely recall some issues with `ZipInputStream` which lead us to use `ZipFile` but for this you will first have to store the file in a temp directoy using the `transferTo` method on `MultipartFile`.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("upload", null);
file.transferTo(tempFile);
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFle(tempFile);
// Proces Zip
tempFile.delete();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get "java.io.IOException: Stream closed" when I try to get an entry: as in...zis.getNextEntry()

Comment: What worked better was by creating the temp file as you suggested. The code was:         File tempFile = new File("content.zip");
        file.transferTo(tempFile);

        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(tempFile);     This created a temp file on disk, and constructed the ZipFile from that. I was finally seeing entries.

Comment: Your welcome, added a temp file sample to the answer instead of only describing it.